# How do I invalidate the service worker cache on deployed Gatsby website on S3 Cloudfront?

Tags: deployment, amazon-cloudfront, browser-cache, gatsby

I am building my first Gatsby website. We host it on AWS S3. Also we use `gatsby-plugin-offline`.

So far I'm not able to find a good solution on how to invalidate the cache after a new deployment.

Even if I manually de-register sw.js service worker and clean the site data via Devtools -> Application -> Clear Storage, the browser keeps loading a cached version (missing added pages, displaying old text content, etc.).

For deployment I use `amplify`.

How do you invalidate an old cache when deploying a new build?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the amplify configuration of [gatsby-auth-starter-aws-amplify](https://github.com/dabit3/gatsby-auth-starter-aws-amplify) ? The offline plugin is active in this starter and [it is the recommended starter for deploying gatsby to amplify](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/deploying-to-aws-amplify/).

Another solution would be to use [the s3 plugin with aws-cli](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/deploying-to-s3-cloudfront/)

[Gatsby's caching docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/caching/) explains caching rules for Gatsby to work well. Common problems are caused by HTML pages' caching (The cache-control header in HTML files should be `cache-control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate`)